# How to include if-statement with decision variables in cplex constraints properly

Tags: if-statement, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, cplex, opl

This is similar to a problem of moving from a decentralized system to a centralized one. Therefore, I want to identify the optimal locations to use as centralized points and the locations that need to be closed. These are my binary decision variables Xi and Yj.
I have two constraints that include an if-statement with decision variables. I have read that in this case I must use logical constraints, so I did.

```
forall (i in Drives, j in Locations)(Y[j]==1 && Distance[j][i]<=20) => X[i]==0;
```

I want this constraint to say that if a location j is chosen (Yj = 1) and if the distance between i and j is less than 20 , then => I want to close location i (Xi = 0)

```
forall (j in Locations, k in Locations)(Y[j]==1 && Distance2[j][k]<=40) => Y[k]==0;
```

Similarly, this constraint says that if a location j is chosen (Yj = 1) and if the distance between 2 potential locations is less than 40, then I do not want to choose location k (Yk = 0)

The model gives a result but as I check the numbers, it seems to ignore these 2 constraints. So, something is not working properly in the terms used.

Answer (score 2):

The constraints look mostly correct to me. What looks a bit fishy in the second constraint is that you don't exclude the case j==k. If Y[j]==1 then probably `Distance2[j][j]==0` and thus the second constraint implies Y[j]==0. A contradiction!
Are you sure that CPLEX claims your solution optimal? Or are you maybe looking at a relaxed solution (which would then be allowed to violate constraints)?

Assuming `Distance` is data and not a decision variable, your constraints could be written in a more efficient way. For example the first one:

```
forall(i in Drives)
   forall(j in Locations : Distance[j][i] <= 20)
      X[i] <= 1 - Y[j]; // If Y[j]==1 then the right-hand side becomes zero and forces X[i]==0
```

Similary, the second constraint could be written as

```
forall(j in Locations)
   forall(k in Locations : k != j && Distance2[j][k] <= 40)
      Y[k] <= 1 - Y[j]; // If Y[j]==1 then the right-hand side becomes zero and forces Y[k]==0
```

Can you try with these more explicit constraints or at least with excluding the case j==k in the second constraint?

Comment: Thank you. I have used the constraints format you have suggested and they seem to be working. However, another problem arises and I am not quite sure if it's relevant to these constraints or not. Maybe you can give me your insight about that:

X[i] belongs to a set of locations from 1 till 715 and Y[j] belongs to a set of locations from 1 till 78. The results I receive only consider the first 78 points in my X[i] and not the whole list. I cannot identify the problem, and I'm not sure if it is arising from these 2 constraints.

Comment: This smells like you are using the wrong index set in some place. Double check that you always use the correct one of `Locations` and `Drives` in all places. If you cannot find the problem then please create a new question and attach your full model.